I need block/unblock feature for our app but "Unblock" part is not working
I have an issue with my code, and ChatGPT and Microsoft Copilot don't fix my issue. Even I have sent all the codes and screenshots.
Here is my HTML code.

        <!-- MESSENGER -->
        <div class="messenger">
            <!-- LEFT -->
            <div class="left-block">
                <div class="search-box">
                    <div class="input-with-icon">
                        <div class="search-input-dark">
                            <input
                                class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Search..."
                            />
                            <i class="bi-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="chat-boxes">
                    <div class="chat-box" id="chat-box-1">
                        <img
                            class="avatar-56"
                            src="img/avatar-model.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                        <div class="chat-content">
                            <div class="chat-top">
                                <div class="name">
                                    <h6 class="fw-medium">Penny Sinnap</h6>
                                </div>

                                <div class="time-and-dots">
                                    <p class="time">30 sec.ago</p>
                                    <div
                                        class="icon-wrapper three-dots"
                                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                        aria-expanded="false"
                                    >
                                        <i class="bi-three-dots"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                id="blockOption"
                                                class="dropdown-item"
                                                href="#"
                                                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                                data-bs-target="#blockModal"
                                                data-chat-box-id="chat-box-1"
                                                >Block User</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a
                                                class="dropdown-item delete-chat-trigger"
                                                href="#"
                                                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                                data-bs-target="#deleteModal"
                                                data-chat-box-id="chat-box-2"
                                                >Delete Chat</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- 3 DOTS MODALS -->

                                    <!-- 3 DOTS MODALS -->

                                    <!-- 3 DOTS TOASTERS -->

                                    <!-- Block Toast -->
                                    <div
                                        class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3"
                                    >
                                        <div
                                            id="blockToast"
                                            class="toast align-items-center"
                                            role="alert"
                                            aria-live="assertive"
                                            aria-atomic="true"
                                        >
                                            <div class="d-flex">
                                                <div class="toast-body">
                                                    You have successfully
                                                    blocked
                                                    <strong
                                                        >Penny Sinnap</strong
                                                    >
                                                </div>
                                                <button
                                                    type="button"
                                                    class="btn-close me-2 m-auto"
                                                    data-bs-dismiss="toast"
                                                    aria-label="Close"
                                                ></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Block Toast -->

                                    <!-- Delete Toast -->
                                    <div
                                        class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3"
                                    >
                                        <div
                                            id="deleteToast"
                                            class="toast align-items-center"
                                            role="alert"
                                            aria-live="assertive"
                                            aria-atomic="true"
                                        >
                                            <div class="d-flex">
                                                <div class="toast-body">
                                                    Your chat successfully
                                                    deleted.
                                                </div>
                                                <button
                                                    type="button"
                                                    class="btn-close me-2 m-auto"
                                                    data-bs-dismiss="toast"
                                                    aria-label="Close"
                                                ></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Delete Toast -->

                                    <!-- 3 DOTS TOASTERS -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                Id ipsum in cras volutpat nam sollicitudin diam
                                vitae. Habitant sit sodales placerat. Id ipsum
                                in cras volutpat nam sollicitudin diam vitae.
                                Habitant sit sodales placerat.Id ipsum in cras
                                volutpat nam sollicitudin diam vitae. Habitant
                                sit sodales placerat. Id ipsum in cras volutpat
                                nam sollicitudin diam vitae. Habitant sit
                                sodales placerat.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block-overlay hidden" id="block-overlay-1">
                            <div class="block-message">
                                You have blocked <strong>Penny Sinnap.</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div
                                class="icon-wrapper three-dots"
                                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-expanded="false"
                            >
                                <i class="bi-three-dots"></i>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        id="blockOption"
                                        class="dropdown-item"
                                        href="#"
                                        data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                        data-bs-target="#blockModal"
                                        >Unblock User</a
                                    >
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        id="deleteButton"
                                        class="dropdown-item"
                                        href="#"
                                        data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                        data-bs-target="#deleteModal"
                                        >Delete Chat</a
                                    >
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    
(And other checboxes...)
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/yhSYY80w.png)
                    <!-- Block/Unblock Modal -->
                    <div
                        class="modal fade warning-modals"
                        id="blockModal"
                        tabindex="-1"
                        aria-labelledby="blockModalLabel"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    >
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5
                                        class="modal-title fs-5 fw-medium"
                                        id="blockModalLabel"
                                    >
                                        Block User
                                    </h5>
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        class="btn-close"
                                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                        aria-label="Close"
                                    ></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>
                                        Are you sure you want to block
                                        <strong class="chat-user-name"
                                            >Penny Sinnap</strong
                                        >?
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-link close-button"
                                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                    >
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                    <button
                                        id="blockToastBtn"
                                        type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-primary"
                                    >
                                        Block
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <!-- LEFT -->
        </div>
        <!-- MESSENGER -->


And here is my javascript code:
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chatBoxToBlock;

    // Capture the chat-box ID when the block-user link is clicked
    $('.dropdown-item[data-bs-target="#blockModal"]').on('click', function () {
        const chatBoxId = $(this).closest('.chat-box').attr('id');
        chatBoxToBlock = chatBoxId;
        updateBlockModalContent(chatBoxToBlock);
    });

    $('#blockToastBtn').click(function () {
        toggleBlock(chatBoxToBlock);
        $('#blockModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#blockModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        chatBoxToBlock = null;
    });

    function updateBlockModalContent(chatBoxId) {
        var chatUser = $('#' + chatBoxId)
            .find('.name h6')
            .text();
        var isBlocked =
            $('#' + chatBoxId)
                .find('.dropdown-item[data-bs-target="#blockModal"]')
                .text()
                .trim() === 'Unblock User';

        var modalLabel = isBlocked ? 'Unblock User' : 'Block User';
        var actionText = isBlocked ? 'unblock' : 'block';
        var buttonText = isBlocked ? 'Unblock' : 'Block';

        // Update modal content based on block/unblock state
        $('#blockModalLabel').text(modalLabel);
        $('#blockModal .modal-body').html(
            '<p>Are you sure you want to ' +
                actionText +
                ' <strong>' +
                chatUser +
                '</strong>?</p>'
        );
        $('#blockToastBtn').text(buttonText);
    }

    function toggleBlock(chatBoxId) {
        var isBlocking = $('#blockToastBtn').text().trim() === 'Block';

        // Toggle the overlay visibility for blocking/unblocking
        var overlay = $('#' + chatBoxId).find('.block-overlay');
        if (isBlocking) {
            overlay.removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
        } else {
            overlay.removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
        }

        // Update button and dropdown item text for Block/Unblock
        $('#' + chatBoxId)
            .find('.dropdown-item[data-bs-target="#blockModal"]')
            .text(isBlocking ? 'Unblock User' : 'Block User');

        // Show toast message
        showToast(
            isBlocking ? 'You have blocked ' : 'You have unblocked ',
            chatBoxId
        );
    }

    function showToast(message, chatBoxId) {
        var chatUser = $('#' + chatBoxId)
            .find('.name h6')
            .text();
        $('#blockToast .toast-body').text(message + chatUser + '.');
        var toast = new bootstrap.Toast($('#blockToast'));
        toast.show();
    }
});

Everything works till you block the user. But when I click "Unblock", I want to update these three labels:
1- "Block user" title should be "Unblock user"
2- "Are you sure you want to block Penny Sinnap?" should be "Are you sure you want to unblock Penny Sinnap?"
3- "Block" button should be "Unblock"
And I have added a screenshot for my issue.
Plus, I also want to be sure that after "Unblock" user, the overlay should disappear.
This is my first question on Stackover Flow. I hope I could have shared my issue in the correct way; if I couldn't, my apologies. :/
Screenshot

No need to apologies, but perhaps it would be helpful to first read: How do I ask a good question? Check out the editor, and learn how to make a code snippet. Remember that we are real humans, not AI-machines. I also advice strongly to not overly rely on AI to program, you have to understand the code you're using. This is especially important when comes to the safety of your code.

You are right. I should have read that article before posting. :/ Thank you very much for the information, and I also agree with you about AI support, but I'm not an expert JavaScript developer, unfortunately. Something really works with ChatGPT, but some minor issues are not.
